# Access instance object inside Closure PHP

Tags: php, closures

I want to access the `$a` object method myMethod() with all `$a` object's properties inside overriden function. How can I do it? Thanks a lot for your help .

```
$a = new A('property');
$a->testFunc = Closure::bind(function() {
    // here the object scope was gone...
    $a->myMethod();
    $this->var = "overridden";
}, $a);
```

Comment: Declare $a global inside the function.

Comment: You can also use the `use` keyword when defining your function. `function() use ($a) { ... }`. This will include the variable inside the function's scope without making it a global variable.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Also, `global $a` would only work if you were in a global scope. If this was already in another function's scope, you would have to define `$a` global in both scopes (first to elevate it to global and second to access it once it was global). And `global ` considered bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `use` keyword when defining your function like this:

```
$a = new A('property');
$a->testFunc = Closure::bind(function() use ($a) {
    // here the object scope was gone...
    $a->myMethod();
    $this->var = "overridden";
}, $a);
```

This will tell php to include `$a` as part of your function's scope.